# Linux kernel configuration - enabling CONFIGURE_LOCALVERSION_AUTO

Tags: linux, git, configuration, linux-kernel

I have recently git cloned the kernel of Linus Torvalds. I want to build and install this kernel in my laptop. But because I want to use "kernel-of-the-day" I want to enable `CONFIGURE_LOCALVERSION_AUTO` option. But how should I enable this option I don't know that. Where to find this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `menuconfig` or `xconfig`, to configure Linux kernel these interfaces are used. Modifying .config file directly is discouraged. Inside your kernel source tree do `make menuconfig` or `make xconfig` - use anyone you like. On kernel configuration menu you'll find `General Setup` Option, inside this option you'll find `Automatically append version information to the version string`, toggle it to enable/disable.

Answer (score 1):

After you have cloned the Linus repository repository. You would need to either create a fresh `.config` file in the `./linux` folder or copy the existing `config` file from your `/boot` and later modify it. Then edit the `.config` file and set `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=y`

```
`cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config`
```

Comment: Unbelivable. First time I read "you have to set this option to your kernel" I spent about few hours in order to find out WHERE. Thanks man, for pointing me to the `.config` file. It may be obvious for you but I got annoyed by this.